# ¿Se usa «latinx» fuera de EE. UU.?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, estados-unidos, neutralidad-de-género

**Por favor, mantengan neutral el tono de esta publicación.**  El propósito de esta publicación es abordar el uso, o la falta del mismo, de un término contemporáneo y hasta qué punto se ha incluido en el léxico español.  Esta publicación no aborda si la palabra se considera correcta, y temo que lenguaje que juzga este término o términos similares estropearía la discusión.

---

Mi universidad angloparlante (La Universidad de Texas en Dallas) ha abrogado formalmente las palabras inglesas *Latino/a* e incluso la palabra neutra *Latin*.  Se espera que toda comunicación oficial use el término *Latinx* en su lugar (a excepción de referir a un individuo conocido).

¿Ha sido usado últimamente, hasta algún nivel perceptible, el término *latinx* (o una palabra similar) en otros países hispanohablantes?

Answer (score 5):

En **España**, no se usa mucho el término *latinos*, y se habla más de *sudamericanos* o *latinoamericanos*. En cuanto a la neutralidad de género, la versión con "x" de las palabras **no** se utiliza mucho, ni en el habla cotidiana ni en comunicaciones oficiales.

Por ejemplo, en [esta publicación](https://www.boe.es/diario_boe/txt.php?id=BOE-A-2020-11590) en el Boletín Oficial del Estado (donde se publican las nuevas leyes), si buscas "ciudadan*" verás que se habla con frecuencia de "los ciudadanos", es decir, que se usa el masculino genérico.

Como en muchos países, esto es un tema político/controvertido, por lo que otras instituciones lo hacen de otra manera. Por ejemplo, en [este comunicado](https://podemos.info/ante-el-enfrentamiento-en-el-mediterraneo-oriental-podemos-reclama-justicia-social-dialogo-derecho-internacional-y-derechos-humanos/) de Podemos (un partido conocido por abogar por la neutralidad de género), se utilizan palabras que no requieren marca de género para garantizar la neutralidad, como por ejemplo "las personas refugiadas".

Es difícil probar un negativo, pero diría que la versión con "x" es muy poco común en España. Existen ciertas asociaciones que abogan por su uso y la usan siempre, pero parecen ser bastante minoritarias/alternativas.

**Nota:** los ejemplos que pongo en esta respuesta son relevantes para el tema lingüístico que se discute, pero su elección no se debe interpretar como apoyo a sus  contenidos o a las instituciones que los publican

Comment: La página de Podemos parece estar caída ahora mismo. espero que se arregle pronto: si no, cambiaré el ejemplo.

Comment: (a mí me funciona el enlace a la web de Podemos)

Comment: Ejemplo de publicación de Podemos en el que se usa el _lxs_: [Concentración por los derechos de lxs refugiadxs. No al acuerdo UE-Turquía - Podemos Aragón](https://aragon.podemos.info/concentracion-por-los-derechos-de-lxs-refugiadxs-no-al-acuerdo-ue-turquia/). En general, yo sí la veo bastante en las publicaciones de entidades de izquierda alternativa. Lo que me sorprende es que la use una universidad, que generalmente (igual que el BOE) suele ser más _conservadora_ en cuanto al uso de la lengua.

Comment: I am sure I have seen latinx used in an English language publication but I am afraid I cannot remember where nor from which anglophone country it came.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' hmm en esa publicación se usa la forma con "x" dos veces, pero se usa el masculino genérico ("los refugiados") cuatro veces. Al menos en ese artículo, no parece que sean muy cuidadosos (sí, yo sí uso el masculino genérico) con el tema.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' My university is by no means conservative. I know Texas consistently votes red in presidential elections, but Dallas, Houston and Austin are exceptions. My university is notorious for being the most liberal in Texas.

Comment: Era un ejemplo. Pueden verse muchos otros casos por ejemplo [en rebelion.org](https://rebelion.org/?s=lxs), [en directa](https://directa.cat/?s=lxs) y demás. Mi punto es que es un uso que veo de forma recurrente en este espacio ideológico en España.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' ya veo, esos grupos parecen ya demasiado alternativos para que yo los conozca (al menos rebelion.org; Directa no la conozco porque parece ser catalana). En cualquier caso, el uso de la "x" en España parece menos extendido que en EEUU en el sentido de que no parece que las universidades o las instituciones del gobierno la usen. He añadido esto a la respuesta, esperemos no derivar en un debate político...

Comment: No, no, para nada es mi intención. Simplemente lo expongo como reflejo de la realidad española, que en un subsector veo que la usa. Y sí, totalmente de acuerdo en que las instituciones no parecen usarlo aquí, al menos en todo aquello que yo conozco y leo no lo he encontrado.

Comment: A pesar de que se escribe a veces una *x* en lugar de la vocal, en el habla, siempre se pronuncia con *o*.

Comment: @user0721090601 ah sí? Eso no parece tan "neutral de género"... Yo oigo mucho lo de "ciudadanos y ciudadanas" en España.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esta pregunta se trata mas sobre el uso del "x" que la palabra "latinx" en concreto.

En México es muy común el uso del "x" en palabras como "amigxs", "todxs", "nosotrxs", particularmente entre la gente progresiva políticamente, por ejemplo feministas o anarquistas. Tal vez no se usa tanto en comunicaciones oficiales de institutos bien establecidos, pero sí se ha difundido mucho entre la gente en general y viviendo aquí, lo veo con frecuencia.

Además he visto su uso proveniente de otros paises latinoamericanos, especialmente común en Chile creo, y hasta Brasil tiene una serie de tv que se llama "Todxs Nosotrxs", lo cual se estrenó este año.

Editado para enlazar unos ejemplos entre muchos que se pueden encontrar.

https://nosotrxs.org/ - MX
https://ardelibros.com/nosotrxs/ - CL
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todxs_Nosotrxs - BR

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar a que parte de México te refieres? En mi caso, es la primera vez que me topo con el uso de la X de esa manera. Aunque no me sorprendería que un grupo reducido de personas estuviera abogando por tal uso, no es, como afirmas, de uso común.

Comment: Wow, el enlace de Wikipedia dice incluso cómo se pronuncia "Todxs Nosotrxs"...

Comment: @Krauss Sobre todo se usa por el internet y en escritura, en publicaciones por gente atenta al ambiente político de donde proviene el concepto. Casi nunca he escuchado, por ejemplo "todes nosotres". Algo parecido que sí escucho sería "amiguis".

Con respeto a tu punto de uso común, tienes razón que no se usa con tal frecuencia como una palabra cotidiana. Pero no es raro encontrarlo en cualquier parte de la republica en su ambiente, lo político, particularmente el ambiente activista como comenté.

Answer (score 0):

Hablo desde España y es la primera vez que me tropiezo con la palabra *latinx*.

Aparte de la respuesta meramente estadística de si se usa o no, me permito añadir algunas consideraciones.

Aquí la palabra *latino* se usa poco, y, cuando se usa, puede ser con acepciones muy diferentes a las de la palabra inglesa.

Resumen de las acepciones del DRAE:

> 1. Natural del Lacio, región de Italia.
> 2. Perteneciente o relativo a los pueblos del Lacio, o a las ciudades con     derecho latino.
> 3. Perteneciente o relativo al latín, o propio de él. Gramática latina.
> 4. Perteneciente o relativo a la Iglesia latina. Los ritos latinos.
> 5. Dicho de una persona: De alguno de los pueblos que hablan lenguas derivadas del latín.
> 6. Perteneciente o relativo a los pueblos que hablan lenguas derivadas del latín. Los países latinos de América. El carácter latino.
> 7. Dicho de una embarcación o de un aparejo: De vela triangular.
> 8. Que sabe latín.
> 9. Acortamiento de "latinoamericano".
> 10. Dicho de una persona: Que es de origen latinoamericano o hispánico y vive en los Estados Unidos de América.

Compárese con las acepciones del Merriam-Webster:

> 1. a native or inhabitant of Latin America
> 2. a person of Latin American origin living in the U.S.

Me parece difícil que una variante de la palabra inglesa, cuyo significado es solo uno de los de la palabra española, pueda llegar a tener un uso mínimamente frecuente en español, salvo entre los aficionados a hacer traducciones *a mocosuena*.

Por otro lado, en español hay recursos alternativos. Si hablas de *personas*, usas el femenino y ya eres inclusivo. También es inclusivo hacerlo en masculino refiriéndote a *habitantes*, por ejemplo. Luego no parece que haga falta inventar ninguna otra palabra en español por este motivo.

Comment: "Me parece difícil que una variante de la palabra inglesa [...], pueda llegar a tener un uso mínimamente frecuente en español" en España es difícil, pero en Latinoamérica ocurre mucho.